# ReactJs Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to implement a login view, but keeps getting error:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
>   repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
>   componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops.

when clicking on the submit button.

```
import './LoginView.css'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Button, TextField, CircularProgress } from '@material-ui/core'
import Auth from '../../utils/Auth'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import Network from '../../utils/Network'
import Toast, { IToastData, ToastType } from '../Toast/Toast'
import AdManager from '../../utils/AdManager'
import pkg from '../../../package.json'
import Logo from "../../assets/logo.png"

export default function LoginView() {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
    const [toastData, setToastData] = useState<IToastData | undefined>(undefined)

    const onSubmit = async () => {
        try {
            setIsLoading(true)
            await Network.instance.login(username, password)
            const success = Auth.instance.isLoggedIn()
            if (success) {
                await AdManager.instance.start()
            }
        } catch (error) {
            setToastData({
                type: ToastType.Error,
                message: "Something went wrong!"
            })
        } finally {
            setIsLoading(false) // According to react this is the culprit
        }
    }

    const createInputFields = () => {
        return (
            <>
                <TextField
                    className="textField"
                    label="Username"
                    type="email"
                    margin="normal"
                    onChange={x => setUsername(x.target.value)}
                    required={true}
                />
                <TextField
                    className="textField"
                    label="Password"
                    type="password"
                    margin="normal"
                    onChange={x => setPassword(x.target.value)}
                    required={true}
                />
            </>
        )
    }

    if (Auth.instance.isLoggedIn()) {
        const path = (AdManager.instance.sources.length === 1) ? '/' : '/selection'
        return <Redirect to={path} />
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div className="root">
                <img src={Logo} className="Logo" alt="Logo" />
                <div className="TextFieldsContainer">
                    {isLoading ? <CircularProgress /> : createInputFields()}
                </div>
                <Button className="button" variant="contained" component="span" disabled={isLoading || (!username || !password)} onClick={onSubmit}>
                    Log in
                </Button>
                {!!toastData && <Toast open={true} message={toastData.message} type={toastData.type} />}
            </div>
            <div className="VersionNumber">{pkg.version}</div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: `setState` is async action. So you should put `try { ...` inside `setState`'s callback. Chain them.

Comment: and use `finally` after catch

Comment: If by setState you mean onSubmit, then it's already async. I added finally (thanks), but the result is the same.

Comment: From your codes, i don't see anythings weirds. it should work fine. but if i can guess, i'm guessing the `setToastData` that u called inside try and catch scope. could you try to use useEffect to watch the toastData values ? and setLoading to false, if toastData changing

Comment: I tried removing ToastData completely and still get the same result

Comment: Cannot reproduce your error - look [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-57745382-n01kd). Please share the rest of your code - maybe createInputFields triggers some loop?

Comment: @ford04 Added code for input fields. All this happened after I opened Chrome Dev tools and clicked Application -> Clear Storage -> Clear site data to see that it worked from a clean slate (even though react scripts should have me covered there)

I could swear all this worked prior to that.

Comment: Added the exact code

Comment: Can you post a working sandbox or the stacktrace?

Comment: This is likely due to some component relying on the data from the state, which either updates too far down or triggers some loop.

Comment: I've solved the issue and it has nothing to do with this component at all. This is just ReactJs throwing me off with a faulty error message. Thank you all for giving me some of your time. :)

Comment: You could post it as answer to help future readers. This error message seems to be not uncommon.

Comment: Agree with ford04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue and while the error was indirectly invoked by the specified line React complained about; the actual cause was a line of code in the component redirected to.

To summarize. React was correct in its' error message, but wasn't specific enough to provide any actual help. I found the error using [git bisect](https://flaviocopes.com/git-bisect/). Having commited often and scoping commits was a saviour here.

Comment: didn't know about bisect, thanks. Was the problem in the other component actually some setState/render loop that cause above error?

Comment: @ford04 The faulty line caused a redirect back to the LoginComponent which in turn redirected back to the component with the faulty line etc. Basically a condition invoking `<redirect ...>` back and forth.